# Facebook api: get a list of apps a specific user is admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve a user's apps list. I use `manage_pages` permissions as stated in the docs. But it only gives me the pages I administer and not my apps (I have about 8 apps in my account).

What can be the cause? Maybe it's only specific types of apps? Maybe I need to turn a flag in my app setting for it to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier it was possible with the following endpoint, but it is deprecated: `/me/applications/developer`

Afaik there is no way to get the list of applications anymore.